# How to set value of a radio button inside a radio group android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to use radio groups where it has 2 radio buttons inside. I wanted to set a value for each radio buttons like for example the value is male and female. After that when I have already click on of my radio button  it will display the value selected. How can you achieve this? Thank you for the help.

i have tried something like this just to test on how will i set a value

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View radioButton) {
    int count = radioGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View o = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (o instanceof RadioButton) {

            RadioButton radioBtn =  (RadioButton)o;
            // get the state
            boolean isChecked = radioBtn.isChecked();
            // to set the check
            radioBtn.setChecked(true);

        }
    }
}
```

but i think its not what i'm looking for.

i have already tried `radioGroup.setId()` assuming that the radio buttons have values already but it just display nonsense number.

Comment: If you haven't tried anything is suggest you do. something that might help: OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: I've updated my question @Karakuri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `RadioGroup` and an [`OnCheckedChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) in your code to detect when a `RadioButton` is selected. In your layout XML:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    ... >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        ... />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        ... />
</RadioGroup>
```

In your Activity/Fragment, set up like so:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        <type> value = <default value>;
        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.radioButton1:
            value = ...;
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            value = ...;
            break;
        }
        // do something with value
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm having an error saying `Cannot resolve method 'setOnCheckedChangedListener()"` should i need to put any import @Karakuri

Comment: There was a typo, I fixed it

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your radio buttons are wrapped in a radio group like below:

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupButtonMale"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupButtonFemale"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```

And in code, to set the value,

```
RadioGroup mySelection = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
int radioButtonId = mySelection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
String selectedValue;
    switch (radioButtonId)
    {
        case R.id.radioGroupButtonMale:
            selectedValue = "Value for Male";
            break;
        case R.id.radioGroupButtonFemale:
            selectedValue = "Value for Female";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You should be using a [`RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).